# How to fetch multiple files from remote machine to local with Ansible

Tags: linux, copy, ansible

I would like to copy files from remote directory to local directory with Ansible but fetch module allows me to copy only one file. I have many servers from which I need files (same directory each server) and I don't now how to do this with Ansible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You will probably need to register remote content and than loop over it, something like this should work:

```
- shell: (cd /remote; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f) | cut -d'/' -f2
  register: files_to_copy

- fetch: src=/remote/{{ item }} dest=/local/
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.stdout_lines }}"
```

where `/remote` should be changed with directory path on your remote server and `/local/` with directory on your master

Comment: By the way, this goes only one level deep (leaves out subdirectories) and ignores directories in general so if that's not something you desire, just change the shell command acordingly.

Comment: What will happen when I run on a bunch of servers? will each register it's own findings? and fetch the right ones?

Comment: any clue how to do this with win_find?  I can't figure out how to extra path from the file list it returns

Comment: Is it also possible to save the fetched file in local in a different name?

Answer (score 46):

You should use the [synchronise module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) to do this. This uses the awesome power of [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). It will copy file & directory structures of any depth, is bulletproof and highly efficient - only copying the actual bytes that have changed:

```yaml
- name: Fetch stuff from the remote and save to local
  synchronize:  src={{ item }} dest=/tmp/ mode=pull
  with_items:
    - "folder/one"
    - "folder/two"
```

The key is the `mode` parameter:

> Specify the direction of the synchronization. In push mode the localhost or delegate is the source; In pull mode the remote host in context is the source.

Comment: I have found the `synchronise` module to be much more reliable and scalable than the other methods ansible has to copy files.

Comment: This is definitely a better way to do it than the accepted answer.

Comment: this module constantly crashes with permission denied (since this is rsync)

Comment: only bad/non bulletproof thing about this is it requires/assumes rsync is installed, when I tried it I got error rsync command not found, so I'll use the other method since I want this to work in internet disconnected environment where I don't control the hosts.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you can leave out the `with_items` if you need to copy a whole folder, just pass it the directory as src= instead.. Then it's *a lot* faster than the accepted solution.

Answer (score 5):

i dont have enough rep to comment otherwise i would add it.

I used what Kęstutis posted.  i had to make a slight modification

```
- shell: (cd /remote; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f) | cut -d'/' -f2
  register: files_to_copy

- fetch: src=/remote/{{ item }} dest=/local/
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.stdout_lines }}"
```

The with_items was the area i had to change. it was not able to locate the files otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Fixing the example above

```
- hosts: srv-test
  tasks:
    - find: paths="/var/tmp/collect" recurse=no patterns="*.tar"
      register: files_to_copy
    - fetch: src={{ item.path }} dest=/tmp
      with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.files }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

well, if you are using latest ansible version, like 2.9.9, I think we need quotes to the item

```
- name: use find to get the files list which you want to copy/fetch
  find: 
    paths: /etc/
    patterns: ".*passwd$"
    use_regex: True   
  register: file_2_fetch

- name: use fetch to get the files
  fetch:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: /tmp/
    flat: yes
  with_items: "{{ file_2_fetch.files }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

i have prepared a playbook which will help to fetch the nmon performance report from server
i have used fetch module with reference of shell module output and able to download the nmon data perfectly

```
---
#NMON PERFORMANCE REPORT FETCH
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: yes
    become: yes
    vars_prompt:
      - name: "date_input"
        prompt: "Enter date to fetch nmon report (YYMMDD) = "
        private: no

    tasks:
      - pause:
          prompt: "\n\n Enter date to fetch nmon report?\n\n--------------------------------------\n\n1. Fetch nmon:\n2. Exist from Playbook:\n\nPlease select Action: \n--------------------------------------\n"
        register: menu

      - set_fact:
          option: "{{ menu.user_input }}"

      
      - name: Find-out nmon report for given date  {{ inventory_hostname }}
        shell: |
          ls -l /var/nmon/data/* | grep -i {{ date_input }} |awk '{print $NF}'
        register: nmon_files_to_copy
        when: option == "1"

      - name: 'Fetch the NMON Report {{ date_input }} output from server {{ inventory_hostname }}'
        fetch:
          src: "{{ item }}"
          dest: /tmp/
          flat: yes
        with_items: "{{ nmon_files_to_copy.stdout_lines }}"
        when: option == "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: srv-test
  tasks:
    - find: paths="/var/tmp/collect" recurse=no patterns="*.tar"
      register: file_to_copy
    - fetch: src={{ item }} dest=/tmp
      with_items: files_to_copy.stdout_lines
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Has this been tried?

Answer (score 0):

I use this:
 1. Pull directories from remote host to specific hosts

```
- name: Gather hosts stats from other hosts
  shell: " scp -r {{results_root_dir_src}} root@{{groups['profiling_server'][0]}}:{{results_root_dir_dest}}/abc/"
  when: "'profiling_server' not in group_names"
#It will not run on the node where the directories need to be copied.
```

3. Pull directories from node to localhost

```
- name: Gather from host to local
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  run_once: true
  become: false
  shell: "scp -r root@{{groups['profiling_server'][0]}}:{{results_root_dir}} ./results_local_location "
```

inventory

```
[nodes]
server1
server2
server3
[profiling_server]
server1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
- shell: (cd /remote; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f) | cut -d'/' -f2
  register: files_to_copy

- fetch: src=/remote/{{ item }} dest=/local/ flat=yes
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation why this is better than the answers already given?

Comment: I observed that when i use [this](https://serverfault.com/a/1087454/946032) code "without" **flat=yes** then targeted files got copied from whole path. So i suggested to add **flat=yes**

Comment: @Sagarbobade Welcome to Server Fault! Please [edit your answer](https://serverfault.com/posts/1087454/edit) to include the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

you can compress your folder and fetch that.
{{inventory_hostname}} good file name for 'tgz' file in your ansible server

```
- name: Compress folder
  community.general.archive:
    path: "/folder/dir"
    dest: "/dst/{{inventory_hostname}}.tgz"
- name: Fetch the file from server
  fetch: 
    src: "/dst/{{inventory_hostname}}.tgz"
    dest: ./backup/ 
    flat: yes
```